# Image not displayed when using it as a background in Tkinter

Tags: python, image, tkinter, background

Hy!
I am trying to use an image as a background in a GUI created in Tkinter. It works fine with the same code on a different frame in this project, but it doesn't want to work in a different frame. I get no error, the frame is just blank.
Thank you for your help!

Here I can use the picture as a background just fine:

```
def main_screen():
global screen
screen = Tk()
screen.geometry("600x750")
screen.configure(background="#022140")
screen.title("Hermes")
filename = PhotoImage(file="background.png")
filename_small = filename.subsample(2, 2)
background_label = Label(image=filename_small)
background_label.place(x=1, y=1, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
login_button = Button(text="Login", bg="#022140", height="2", width="30", command=login,
                      highlightbackground='#494B68')
screen.mainloop()
```

But here it won't work:

```
def login_sucess():
    global screen3
    screen3 = Toplevel(screen)
    screen3.geometry("500x400")
    filename = PhotoImage(file="main_theme.png")
    filename_small = filename.subsample(2, 2)
    background_label = Label(screen3, image=filename_small)
    background_label.place()
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: For the first case, did `screen.mainloop()` called inside `main_screen()`?  If no, the background picture should not be shown (same as second case).

Comment: I tried that, it changes nothing.

Comment: What did you try? Calling `screen.mainloop()` inside `main_screen()` or outside?  As I said, the image will be shown if it is called inside function, but not if it is called outside function.

Comment: I tried calling screen3.mainloop() inside the function def login_success():

Comment: For the second case, better not calling `screen3.mainloop()` as there is already a mainloop (`screen.mainloop()`) running.

Comment: Maybe giving you a little more syntax will help, for now this is an app, where you can either login or register in it. This is what the first code that I posted is intended to do. In there I added a background that is working fine. The second code that I have posted is a window that opens when you login successfully, and this is where I can not add the background image. The `screen.mainloop()` is running inside the function.

Comment: So you better update the code to show the actual situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be quite simple. When you're working with images in tkinter you always need to set a reference to that image on the widget you used it on. In other words do something like this:

```py
from tkinter import Tk,Label,PhotoImage

root = Tk()
img = PhotoImage(file='background.png')
small_img=img.subsample(2, 2)
background_label = Label(root, image=small_img)
background_label.img=img
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relheight=1, relwidth=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Especially when you create the Label holding the image in a functions scope or something similar it's important to set that reference since the variable to that Labels instance will be gone after the function call ends.

PS: To be more clear about master widgets and for small performance improvements always give a widget a master widget when initializing it. I know tkinter also automatically assigns the last created Tk instance as master itself but a) does that need unneccesary computing power and b) is it easier to keep track of what widget is a child of another and so on. ;)

Comment: I do apologize, being a complete beginner learning to code from internet, could you please clarify what you mean by giving a widget a master widget? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Adde this, and changed the root to screen3 in my case. It worked, thanks!

Comment: No need to apologize, we all have started once. But to explain in all detail what a master widget is would be too long for a comment so instead read this article amd the following: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-whats-tkinter.htm  The explanation is pretty good and from there you can go on to descriptions of other widgets and so on. ^^